# How to make an array of audio files randomly in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio

Im trying to make and array of soundfiles that will play in a random order but not sure... is it possible to make and array of audio files?

maybe like this?

```
var audio = new Audio ["christmas.mp3","jingleBells.mp3"]
audio.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is

```
var audio_files = [
    "christmas.mp3",
    "jingleBells.mp3"
]

var random_file = audio_files[Math.floor(Math.random() * audio_files.length)];

var audio = new Audio(random_file);

audio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var musicFiles = ["play1","play2","play3","play4"];

function play(randomFile){
   return randomFile[Math.floor(Math.random() *  (randomFile.length ))];
}

play(musicFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks adeneo for the reply to this thread, I used the code and it was helpful!

I wanted to make a slight improvement that I notice that it did not get randomized enough.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


function audioplay1(){

var audio_files = ["audiofiles/emotions/afraid.mp3", "audiofiles/emotions/anger.mp3", "audiofiles/emotions/disgust.mp3", "audiofiles/emotions/happy.mp3", "audiofiles/emotions/sad.mp3", "audiofiles/emotions/surprised.mp3", "audiofiles/emotions/disgust.mp3"];
var random_file = audio_files[getRandomInt(0,audio_files.length)];

var audio = new Audio(random_file);

audio.play();
}
```